# $JAVA_HOME variable changes with each new terminal

Tags: java, shell, export, cloudera, java-home

I recently installed Jdk1.8 on my machine. Everything went well and I made it work. After that I edited my **/etc/profile** file in order to set the new Java path. I edited the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

and then I executed

```
source /etc/profile
```

Here again everything went fine and I could see the changes on the terminal.

Problem is:

Everytime I open a new terminal I need to do

```
source /etc/profile
```

or else JAVA_HOME would have its old value.

Solution please? Thank you

Comment: why not change the environment settings themselves?

Comment: JAVA_HOME was JDK1.7 directory before. I installed 1.8 so I changed it to its repertory

Comment: See this question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal

Comment: Had this before, try restarting your VM/computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your username is 'test', then create a file called /home/test/.profile if it does not exist, and add your export command there.

Comment: isn't there a way to apply changes to all users ?

Comment: Then what you did works..just try restarting your terminal and see if it works

Comment: Also, what is the output of `update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: 1 ============== /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

Comment: There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

Comment: try selecting 1 on the prompt..It should work as it is showing your required jdk there..

Comment: Also do the same for javac config